# play 1.2.5 multiple database connection

Tags: oracle, hibernate, playframework

I am using play 1.2.5 framework in my application. Play use JPA API to use hibernate. Issue I am facing here, that I want to use multiple database connections in my application, so that a part of my application could use different DB, but play 1.2.5 doesn't support multiple DB connection. Automatically it will give connection details from application.conf file to entitymanager by:

view plainprint?
Note: Text content in the code blocks is automatically word-wrapped

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = JPA.em().getCriteriaBuilder();
```

Is there any alternative and easy way to do it?

I've come across a solution mention below:

view plainprint?
Note: Text content in the code blocks is automatically word-wrapped

```
ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.42.20.25:1521/TEST");  
        ds.setUser("CODACUSER");  
        ds.setPassword("CODACUSER");  
        ds.setAcquireRetryAttempts(10);  
        ds.setCheckoutTimeout(5000);  
        ds.setBreakAfterAcquireFailure(false);  
        ds.setMaxPoolSize(30);  
        ds.setMinPoolSize(1);  
        ds.setMaxIdleTimeExcessConnections(0);  
        ds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(10);  
        ds.setTestConnectionOnCheckin(true);  
        //EbeanServer secondary = Ebean.getServer("secondary");  
        //Connection conn = DB.getDBConfig("new").getConnection();  
        DB.datasource = ds;  
        try {  
            connection = ds.getConnection();  
        } catch (SQLException e) {  

            e.printStackTrace();    

    }   

enter code here
```

I am able to establish a connection here but how to pass this connection to JPA and entity manager is not yet clear...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [multidb](http://www.playframework.com/modules/multidb) module?

Comment: is this support by Play 1.2.5?

Comment: It is a Play 1 module and should work with 1.2.5 but I have never tried it myself.